# Is it possible to install CoffeeScript into the node.js in Photoshop CC?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, photoshop

I'm grappling with the HTML5 + JS path for writing photoshop extensions, and I'd like to use Coffee instead of plain JS.

However the node install included with Photoshop appears to be version 0.10.30 and does not seem to include npm.  Is there a way to install npm into the photoshop version of node? Or would it be save to replace that version with one which includes npm?  As a last resort I can probably install another node with npm, and coffee, then copy the js into the plugins -- but that seems very awkward.

Has anybody tried this already and cracked it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a separate directory for development and a task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to compile your sources into the plugins directory whenever there are changes.

Take a look at some boilerplates to get you started quickly, like [grunt-html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/creativeprogramming/grunt-html5-boilerplate/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee) or [vtex/speed](https://github.com/vtex/speed/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee)

Comment: Seems like a plan! Thansk